# Store members of date in different variables

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, time

Currently I'm running the following code

```
int main() {

    while(1)

        {
            time_t current = time(NULL);
            cout << ctime(&current)<< endl;
        }
}
```

and my output looks like this:

Sun Jan 15 00:03:25 2017

Sun Jan 15 00:03:25 2017

As the hours are 00, mins are 03 and secs are 25. I want to store 00 in some integer variable, let's say **int hrs**, 03 in a variable **int min** and 25 in a variable **int sec**. How to do it?

Comment: put a sample code of what you tried...

Comment: I want a new car. Preferably red.

Comment: So what's the question? Did you run into any specific problem? If you don't even know where to start, please read a good C++ book. Learning C++ by trial and error or through random snippets from the internet does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you want is `localtime`.

This function takes the address of a `time_t` and returns a pointer to a `struct tm` which contains the date and time broken down into year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime):

> ```
> struct tm *localtime(const time_t *timep);
> ```
>
> The `localtime()` function converts the calendar time `timep` to
>   broken-down time representation, expressed relative to the user's
>   specified timezone. The function acts as if it called `tzset(3`) and
>   sets the external variables `tzname` with information about the current
>   timezone, timezone with the difference between Coordinated Universal
>   Time (UTC) and local standard time in seconds, and daylight to a
>   nonzero value if daylight savings time rules apply during some part of
>   the year. The return value points to a statically allocated `struct`
>   which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and
>   time functions.

The definition of `struct tm` is as follows:

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
    int tm_min;         /* minutes */
    int tm_hour;        /* hours */
    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
    int tm_mon;         /* month */
    int tm_year;        /* year */
    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have time look up the `__TIMESTAMP__` variable. Its should look like this: 12 Sat 16 12:00:00